# SSH over a cloud connection, just like RealVNC Connect but for SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, vnc-server

I really like the RealVnc Connect concept as it allows me to contact my devices behind firewalls etc. I'm looking for a similar option for SSH.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found many alternatives myself here:
https://alternativeto.net/software/openport/

Just needed the right google keywords :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try tunnel softwares like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), [PiTunnel](https://www.pitunnel.com/) and [Yaler](https://yaler.net/)